# How to correctly implement BackgroundWorker to inform user that the task is progressing

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

**The Problem**
I have used the project from https://github.com/zaagan/BioMetrix and want to use BackgroundWorker to display a progression during long tasks (Ex: Get Log Data takes about 30 seconds)

**What I've done so far**
1- Added backgroundWorker1 from Toolbox
2- After InitializeComponent(), I've Added :

```
 backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
 backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

3- Added those functions:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, 
 ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }


private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            this.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            this.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }
```

I was expecting to view the progression percentage on the main Caption title text while retrieving log data from the device.

Comment: I would like to discourage use of BGW. Use Task.Run and `IProgress` instead.

Comment: I couldn't put it better than Stephen C himself: [Task.Run vs BackgroundWorker](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) and from that series especially: [Reporting Progress](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html)

Comment: _"I was expecting to view the progression percentage on the main Caption title text "_ what did you get instead?

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for pointing me to Task.Run, and BTW I don't get the expected percentage on the title the UI is frozen until the operation is completed

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the event handler to the event

```
worker.DoWork += backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
```

If you have created a Windows Form you need to looking in events page of the Background Worker properties and find the DoWork event, then assign it a function to run.